# Shorten this code... Append JSON data from Multiple GET requests, then dump into single Excel File with Headers

Tags: python, get

I'm very new to Python.

The API I am using, is limited to 1000 results per request.
I'm trying to get all the results/data for a specific date range, 1 month for this example.

Before I start, I run a GET request to see how many results would need to be exported in total.

For this example, the total = 14,841. I then create 15 queries/requests of 1000 each, using the "start" parameters of 1001, 2001, 3001, etc, and then take the response for each request and save that into a txt file containing the JSON data.

I am sure there is a way to shorten this code & process using Python.
There are times when the Total is over 500,000 results, which forces me to do 500+ requests.

Below is an example of 5 requests / queries.

1. How can I shorten this code to combine multiple queries & data into 1 file?

   import requests

   url = "https://api.leadspedia.com/core/v2/leads/getAll.do"

   headers = {
   'Content-Type': "application/json",
   'Authorization': "Basic XYZ"
   }

   querystring = {"fromDate":"2020-04-01","toDate":"2020-04-30","start":"0","limit":"1000"}
   querystring2 = {"fromDate":"2020-04-01","toDate":"2020-04-30","start":"1001","limit":"1000"}
   querystring3 = {"fromDate":"2020-04-01","toDate":"2020-04-30","start":"2001","limit":"1000"}
   querystring4 = {"fromDate":"2020-04-01","toDate":"2020-04-30","start":"3001","limit":"1000"}
   querystring5 = {"fromDate":"2020-04-01","toDate":"2020-04-30","start":"4001","limit":"1000"}

   response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
   response2 = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring2)
   response3 = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring3)
   response4 = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring4)
   response5 = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring5)

   file = open("out1.txt", "wb")
   file.write(response.content)
   file.close()

   file = open("out2.txt", "wb")
   file.write(response2.content)
   file.close()

   file = open("out3.txt", "wb")
   file.write(response3.content)
   file.close()

   file = open("out4.txt", "wb")
   file.write(response4.content)
   file.close()

   file = open("out5.txt", "wb")
   file.write(response5.content)
   file.close()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a boolean indicating whether you are still obtaining new, valid results and a while loop using it:

```
query_number = 1
start = 0
more_to_query = True

while more_to_query:
  querystring={"fromDate":"2020-04-01","toDate":"2020-04-30","start":str(start),"limit":"1000"} 
  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring) 
  file = open("out" + str(query_number) + ".txt", "wb")
  file.write(response.content) 
  file.close()
  start += 1000
  query_number += 1
  # set more_to_query to False when you detect you're no longer receiving new valid responses
```

Comment: So if I now wanted to append all those requests into 1 file and export to excel, using the info from the responses as headers? Can that also be done in Python?

Comment: I usually use pandas library to deal with data, it has a function to save to excel (to_excel), you can also set the headers there. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html Basically you would have to create a dataframe with requests as rows, I believe.